# Project Euler 022 'Names scores'

Tags: ruby

My solution to [Project Euler 022](https://projecteuler.net/problem=22) is running incorrectly and I can't see why:

```
$scores = {
    "A" => 1,
    "B" => 2,
    "C" => 3,
    ...
    "Z" => 26
}

def alphabetScore(name)
    nameScore = 0
    array = name.split(//)
    array.each { |n| nameScore += $scores[n] }
    return nameScore
end

file = File.read("p022_names.txt").split(",")
file.map! { |n| n.tr('^A-Za-z0-9','') }

totalScore = 0

file.each do |findScore|
    nameScore = alphabetScore(findScore)
    totalScore += nameScore
end

p totalScore
# p file # to check that 'file' is indeed an array of strings
```

Testing individual names e.g `p alphabetScore("AGNES")` returns the correct value but when totaling the score of every name I get `324536`, which is incorrect (the correct answer is `871198282`). My only guess as to why this isn't working is that one of the names (presumably the one which would cause `totalScore` to exceed `324536`) is broken in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed this part of the prompt:

> Then working out the alphabetical value for each name, **multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the list** to obtain a name score.

Comment: Haha completely forgot about that. I'm retarded, sorry everyone.